# Google sheet query is not showing the correct output

Tags: sql, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am working on MIS sheet generation in Google sheets and this query is not showing any output:

```
=ifNA(query(ifcstep1, "select count(A) where A>date'"&E$3&"' and 
A<date'"&I$3&"'label count(A) ''"),"")
```

The same query worked in another cell, E9, but not on the one I wanted, E6. The date E3 is 27 Dec 2020 and I3 is 4 Jan 2021. It is showing no output, which has to be the condition if the output is n/a error, but the output should not be n/a as there are date values to count from the named range ifcstep1. What could be the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the unique way `QUERY` handles date comparisons.  The required syntax is of the form:

```
... where A > date 'yyyy-mm-dd' ...
```

where the yyyy-mm-dd is a text string, not a date value.

So for your specific formula, try the following:

```
=IFNA(QUERY(ifcstep1, 
        "select count(A) where A > date '" & TEXT(E$3,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' and
                               A < date '" & TEXT(I$3,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' 
         label  count(A) '' "),"")
```

This uses the TEXT function to convert your two date values to strings, in the required format, before ding the comparison.

Note that if the values in E3 and I3 are already strings, and not date values, you need to add `DATEVALUE` in front of them, to convert them first to date values, and then back to the correct format strings.

For reference, see this excellent Ben Collins explanation.
https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-dates/